# Is there a process in place to dispute a "duplicate" flag?

Tags: support

I asked a question about my resume saying that I'm over-qualified but that due to illness, I'm not able to meet the requirements of jobs I've held in the past.

It didn't fit into the "how do you handle overqualified" or into the questions about illness.

I read them beforehand and edited my post to make it more clear.

[How do I address both being overqualified, and unable to perform at past levels?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62205/how-do-i-address-both-being-overqualified-and-unable-to-perform-at-past-levels)

Is there a way to dispute this?  I would like more answers, but it's flagged as duplicate

Comment: This _is_ the way to dispute it.  Edit the question so that it's clearer as to what you're asking, then raise a question here indicating why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you.  Good to know I took the right approach

Comment: see also: [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476/165773) and [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253521/839601)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert my comment to an answer:

If you feel that your question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate, then the steps you should take are:

- Edit the question such that it's clearer what you're asking.  Be specific.
- Raise a question here in meta, explaining to the community *why* you feel that it's not a duplicate and why it should be reopened.

The community then can either vote to reopen it, or not.  Note that reopening a question is *not* a moderator function; Stack Exchange is very much based in community moderation, and as such it's the *community* that needs to decide whether a question should be reopened.