# This isn't a duplicate [Reopened]

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

So [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/109458/8146) has been closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/5750/8146).

This is not the case, however.

In the first case, the question is really "I have been given feedback about my interview that I disagree with, I feel I have been misjudged, how do I proceed?".

The second case is "I applied for a role but have been informed that they already found someone. The problem, then is not with me, but with timing. How do I respond to keep my options open with this company for a different role?"

I'm not sure why they are duplicates, they are very different questions. Can we please re-open the former?

**EDIT**
I really don't know what to say, the linked answer here... just says to edit the question to specify why it's not a duplicate. I don't know how to edit the question under discussion as it is *obviously* not a duplicate, it just requires  some basic comprehension skills. I think the trick might be the *titles* of the questions, but the *content* of each  is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a process in place to dispute a "duplicate" flag?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3508/is-there-a-process-in-place-to-dispute-a-duplicate-flag)

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings seriously? What edit do you want, exactly, to clarify that the question being asked is different? A basic grasp of what each questions asks should be specific, as they are *now* they are different, no editing needed

Comment: Unless it is the same and no real edit is going to make it any different effectively. Its the same problem and no variables you listed effect the results.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings please let me know how they are the same question

Comment: You were rejected.  There is nothing you can say that is going to change it.  The reviewer was wrong.  They believe their expert not the candidate.  Nothing you can say is going to change that.  It may not even be the real reason you were rejected.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings *It may not even be the real reason you were rejected*.  Ding, ding, ding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been reopened.